# Is there a simpler way to equip generic structs with a constant besides using traits with associated constants?

Tags: generics, rust, constants

I have a type `Indexer` which goes either `Forward` (+1) or `Backward` (-1). In C++:

```cpp
enum Direction {
    Forward,
    Backward
};

template <Direction Dir>
struct Indexer {
   static constexpr int delta = (Dir == Forward ? 1 : -1);
};

void foo() {
    Indexer<Forward> f;
}
```

This is the best I have come up with to implement this in Rust:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Forward;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Backward;

pub trait Direction: Copy {
    const DELTA: i32;
}

impl Direction for Forward {
    const DELTA: i32 = 1;
}

impl Direction for Backward {
    const DELTA: i32 = -1;
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Indexer<Dir: Direction> {
    pd: PhantomData<Dir>,
}

impl<Dir: Direction> Indexer<Dir> {
    const DELTA: i32 = Dir::DELTA;
}

pub fn run() {
    let idx = Indexer::<Forward> { pd: PhantomData {} };
}
```

The `PhantomData` seems required because I am not storing the `Direction` in a field, and it in turn requires a lot of boilerplate. Is there a simpler way to port this C++ code? I hope to avoid macros or crate dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something that I use in my projects (until rust supports const generics):

```
use std::fmt;

pub trait TStaticValue<
    V: Copy/*prevent interior mutation (suggested by clippy)*/
> : Sync + 'static + Clone + fmt::Debug { // these bounds turned out to be convenient for me
    const VALUE : V;
}

macro_rules! define_static_value {(pub $struct: ident, $type: ty, $value: expr) => {
    #[derive(Clone, Debug)]
    pub struct $struct {}
    impl TStaticValue<$type> for $struct {
        const VALUE : $type = $value;
    }
}}
```

Then, `define_static_value` would allow you to define the following:

```
define_static_value!(pub ForwardDelta, i32, 1);
define_static_value!(pub BackwardDelta, i32, -1);

pub struct Indexer<Dir: TStaticValue<i32>> {
    pd: std::marker::PhantomData<Dir>
}

impl<Dir: TStaticValue<i32>> Indexer<Dir> {
    const DELTA:i32 = Dir::VALUE;
}
```

I know you wanted to avoid macros, but this solution turned out to be relatively maintainable for me, because all "static values" (i.e. const generic parameters) are emulated the same way, and it allows you to define and use them ad hoc and with different types, all via the same architecture: Whenever you actually want a const generic parameter `Param` of type `CG`, you specify `Param: TStaticValue<CG>` instead.

You may want to adjust `define_static_value` to allow for non-`pub` values, too.

A remark regarding `PhandomData`: I did so far not find a way that allowed me to avoid those, but you can make sure that each struct has *at most one* `PhantomData` member by packing all otherwise unused parameters into that respective field (that would then have type `PhantomData<(FirstUnused, SecondUnused, ThirdUnused)>`.

Answer (score 1):

It *really* depends on what exactly you're trying to do here, but one simplification is this:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Direction {
    Forward = 1,
    Backward = -1,
}

impl Direction {
    const fn delta(self) -> isize {
        self as isize
    }
}
```

[When `if` and `match` are allowed in `const` functions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49146), this could, perhaps more idiomatically, be written as

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Direction {
    Forward,
    Backward,
}

impl Direction {
    const fn delta(self) -> isize {
        match self {
            Self::Forward => 1,
            Self::Backward => -1,
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could simply not take `delta` to be constant. In most cases, the compiler will optimize out calls to it anyway. It's only if you actually need the result to be a constant expression that it's necessary.

Here's how you can use this [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=04a3f303b589ff442de26e4a76c14e6e):

```
fn main() {
    let dir = Direction::Forward;

    let mut x: isize = 0;
    for _ in 0..100 {
        x += dir.delta();
    }

    let dir = Direction::Backward;

    for _ in 0..50 {
        x += dir.delta();
    }

    assert_eq!(x, 50);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the unstable `const_generics` feature, I'd write it as:

```rust
// Rust 1.53.0-nightly (2021-03-28 4a20eb6a9da36c88ee92)
#![feature(const_generics)]

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Direction {
    Forward = 1,
    Backward = -1,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Indexer<const DIRECTION: Direction> {}

impl<const DIRECTION: Direction> Indexer<DIRECTION> {}

fn run() {
    let idx = Indexer::<{ Direction::Forward }> {};
}
```

With only the const generic features available in Rust 1.51, you could use:

```rust
const FORWARD: isize = 1;
const BACKWARD: isize = -1;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Indexer<const DIRECTION: isize> {}

impl<const DIRECTION: isize> Indexer<DIRECTION> {}

fn run() {
    let idx = Indexer::<{ FORWARD }> {};
}
```